# How can I leverage Version Control to help manage my photo collection?

Tags: version-control

I want to be able to reference all previous edition of a digital photo (raw, touched, retouched, cropped, etc).

How can I leverage a VCS for this activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you don't: a VCS isn't the right tool for this kind of artifact, mainly because the main features it has won't fit said artifacts: historization and diff. There is no efficient notion of delta between versions.
(As mentioned on [other](http://Version%20control%20solution%20for%20a%20build%20system%20that%20produces%20a%204GB%20ISO) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300964/whats-the-best-way-to-version-control-graphical-assets-on-windows/3302136#3302136))

Binaries (like your photos) can still make sense in a VCS, for release management and deployment purpose (as I mention in "[Alternative to binaries in Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709372/alternative-to-binaries-in-subversion/710090#710090)").
But that is clearly not your case here.

Regarding photos specifically, I would recommend an external open platform actually built to manage the kind of metadata you are mentioning: See [**openphoto**](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/jmathai/openphoto-a-photo-service-for-your-s3-or-dropbox-a), and the [interview done by Robert Scoble](https://plus.google.com/111091089527727420853/posts/TawyUmzfxQd) for more.
You can build your own server by [cloning their frontend on GitHub](https://github.com/openphoto/frontend).